# iOS Web App - Slow JavaScript 'add text to input' button

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

I'm trying to write a kiosk-style web app for iOS. I've created some buttons, which their only purpose is to insert some text into an input box, and everything seems fine. The problem is it's very very slow on the iPad itself.

Here's the function:

```
function addCode(key1){ 
    var input1 = document.getElementById("productid");
input1.value += key1;
}
```

This is the input box:

```
<input type="text" id="productid" name="productid" placeholder="Product ID" readonly="true">
```

And here's how I call the function:

```
<input type="button" value="GEN" onclick="addCode('GEN');">
```

I'm not sure what's the problem here. As I've said, this works fine on my computer, but not on the iPad...

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT: Here's the complete code for the page

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
    <head>
       <title>Find a Product</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/mainfont.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
       <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
       <script>
          function addCode(key1){ 
              var input1 = document.getElementById("productid");
          input1.value += key1;
          }

          function emptyCode(){ 
              var input2 = document.getElementById("productid");
          input2.value = "";
          }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false">
  <div align="center">
     <div id="find">
        <form action="find_product.php" method="POST">
           <fieldset>
              <p><input type="text" id="productid" name="productid" placeholder="Product ID" readonly="true"></p>
              <br />
              <table border="0" width="320px">
                 <!--Row-->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="GEN" onclick="addCode('GEN');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="TST" onclick="addCode('TST');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="CSU" onclick="addCode('CSU');"></p>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--EndRow-->
                 <!--Row-->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="1" onclick="addCode('1');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="2" onclick="addCode('2');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="3" onclick="addCode('3');"></p>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--EndRow-->
                 <!--Row-->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="4" onclick="addCode('4');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="5" onclick="addCode('5');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="6" onclick="addCode('6');"></p>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--EndRow-->
                 <!--Row-->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="7" onclick="addCode('7');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="8" onclick="addCode('8');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="9" onclick="addCode('9');"></p>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--EndRow-->
                 <!--Row-->
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="emptyCode();"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       <p><input type="button" value="0" onclick="addCode('0');"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10px"></td>
                    <td width="100px">
                       &nbsp;
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--EndRow-->
              </table>
              <br />
              <p><input type="submit" value="Find"></p>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
     </div>
          <!-- end login -->
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you put more code? Simply this line cannot perform slow by itself. Do you have a zillion event handlers on the document or something..? Does your page have 9999999 elements..? Mobile devices are slower but they do have a somewhat acceptable engine :P

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? I'm facing a very similar use case and performance issue.